# Setting scope variable to ng-model in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is my code

### HTML

```html
 <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="obj in objsInObj">
        obj.str = <input ng-model="obj.str" />
    </li>
 </ul>
 obj in <code>{{ strA.a1 }}</code>
 obj in <code>{{ strA.a2 }}</code>
```

### Javascript

```js
$scope.strA = {a1:"abc", a2:"bcd"};
$scope.objsInObj = {
    a: {
        str: $scope.strA.a1
    },
    b: {
        str: $scope.strA.a2
    }
};
```

I want to set $scope.strA.a1 and $scope.strA.a2 as ng-model to two text box , here initially the text box value is loading properly but if I change the value inside textbox that is not visible in scope variable

Comment: Why do you loop your object, `objsInObj`? You can loop only array not object?

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand why you need this structure, but this code works fine

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="obj in objsInObj track by $index">
        obj.str = <input ng-model="obj.str" data-ng-change="Modify($index, obj);" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

this is javascript

```
$scope.Modify = function(index, v) {
    $scope.strA["a"+ (index+1)] = v.str;
};
```

here the working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/maurosala/Lr8o0gqb/)